# Grep specific domain and all subdomains from access.log

Tags: apache, bash, logging, grep

I'm trying to grep a specific line with domain from Apache2 access.log. In my access.log I have all my virtual hosts and different domains.

**cat/var/log/access.log:**

```
www.something-else-domain.si:80 193.77.xxx. xxx - - [06/Nov/2013:12:21:45 +0100] "GET /path/to/dir/image.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 - "www.something-else-domain.si/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"

www.domain.si:80 193.77.xxx. xxx - - [06/Nov/2013:12:21:45 +0100] "GET /path/to/dir/image. jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 - "www.domain.si/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"

domain.si:80 193.77.xxx. xxx - - [06/Nov/2013:12:21:45 +0100] "GET /path/to/dir/image. jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 - "www.domain.si/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
```

I would want to grep only the domain.si and www.domain.si and whatever.domain.si and not something-else-domain.si. How could I do that? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
egrep '^([^ ]*\.)?domain\.si' /var/log/access.log
```

Taking this apart:

- `^` is the beginning of the line.
- `(xxx)?` is "match `xxx` or nothing"; in this case, match either:

  - nothing at all, which is the case of a naked domain name (`domain.si`)
  - `[^ ]*\.`, any string of characters that are not spaces, followed by a dot. This matches the optional `www.` or `whatever.` part.
- `domain\.si` simply matches the `domain.si` part.

The anchoring with `^`, along with the "no spaces" bit, ensures that you only match things at the beginning of the line (not requests like `GET /domain.si`).

Answer (score 0):

A `gnu awk` solution

```
awk  '/www.domain$|domanin$/ {print $NF RS}' RS=".si"
www.domain.si
"www.domain.si
"www.domain.si
```

There is a problem in your example. space are not allowed in `url`